# JAVAFX UI bug when loading fxml programatically

Tags: user-interface, javafx, handler, fxml, fxmlloader

Im trying to dynamicaly load an FXML file,

This is the loop which loads five fxml instances:

```
 for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/layout/BoxMachinePriceSettings.fxml"));
                    VBox load = loader.load();
                    vboxMachinePrices.getChildren().add(load);
                    BoxMachinePriceSettings boxMachinePriceSettings = loader.getController();
                    boxMachinePriceSettings.initMachinePricesValues(finalMachinePricesInfoList.get(index));
                }
```

everything works fine until the window is maximized.
when I'm maximazing the screen and Hover one of the nodes with the mouse, the node's graphic becomes blank.
this is the fxml file that I'm loading:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.otot.laundryManager.ui.components.CustomTextField?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox id="boxMachinePriceSettings" fx:id="vboxMachineStatus" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="126.0"
      prefWidth="1567.0" stylesheets="@../css/style.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.otot.laundryManager.logic.BoxMachinePriceSettings">

    <children>
        <BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0"
                    style="-fx-background-color: rgb(255,255,255,0.9); -fx-background-radius: 10 10 0 0;"
                    VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <left>
                <Label fx:id="lblPriceNumer" alignment="TOP_LEFT" minWidth="-Infinity" text="Price 1"
                       BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0"/>
                    </font>
                    <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>
            </left>
            <right>
                <Button id="start_machine_button" fx:id="btnStartMachine" defaultButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false"
                        onAction="#onStartMachine" text="Start Machine" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <graphic>
                        <ImageView cache="true" fitHeight="18.0" fitWidth="79.0" preserveRatio="true">
                            <image>
                                <Image url="@../images/activate_machine.png"/>
                            </image>
                        </ImageView>
                    </graphic>
                    <BorderPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0"/>
                    </BorderPane.margin>
                </Button>
            </right>
            <center>
                <Label fx:id="lblEditPricesStatusMessage" text="Status Messages" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="16.0"/>
                    </font>
                </Label>
            </center>
        </BorderPane>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT"
              style="-fx-background-color: rgba(36, 39, 41, 0.6); -fx-background-radius: 0 0 10 10;"
              VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <children>
                <HBox spacing="5.0"
                      style="-fx-border-color: rgb(255,255,255, 0.5); -fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-radius: 0 0 6 6;"
                      HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <children>
                        <VBox alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                            <children>
                                <HBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                    <children>
                                        <Label text="Machine Price" textFill="WHITE" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                                            <font>
                                                <Font size="17.0"/>
                                            </font>
                                        </Label>
                                    </children>
                                </HBox>
                                <CustomTextField fx:id="txtMachinePrice" alignment="CENTER"
                                                 doubleFormatterEnabled="true" maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0"/>
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                        <VBox alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                            <children>
                                <HBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                    <children>
                                        <Label text="Customer Price" textFill="WHITE">
                                            <font>
                                                <Font size="17.0"/>
                                            </font>
                                        </Label>
                                    </children>
                                </HBox>
                                <CustomTextField fx:id="txtCustomerPrice" alignment="CENTER"
                                                 doubleFormatterEnabled="true" maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0"/>
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                        <VBox alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                            <children>
                                <HBox alignment="CENTER" style="-fx-border-color: white\;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                    <children>
                                        <Label text="Estimated Time" textFill="WHITE">
                                            <font>
                                                <Font size="17.0"/>
                                            </font>
                                        </Label>
                                    </children>
                                </HBox>
                                <CustomTextField fx:id="txtEstimatedTime" alignment="CENTER"
                                                 doubleFormatterEnabled="true" maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0"/>
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                    </children>
                    <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </HBox>
                <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="5.0"
                      style="-fx-border-color: rgb(255,255,255, 0.5); -fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-radius: 0 0 6 6;"
                      HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <children>
                        <VBox alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                            <children>
                                <Label minWidth="-Infinity" text="Adding Time?" textFill="WHITE" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"
                                       VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="17.0"/>
                                    </font>
                                </Label>
                                <HBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                    <children>
                                        <CheckBox fx:id="cbAddingTime" mnemonicParsing="false" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets/>
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </CheckBox>
                                    </children>
                                </HBox>
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                        <HBox fx:id="hboxWorkingPrices" spacing="5.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                            <children>
                                <VBox alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                                    <children>
                                        <HBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                            <children>
                                                <Label text="Estimated Time" textFill="WHITE">
                                                    <font>
                                                        <Font size="17.0"/>
                                                    </font>
                                                </Label>
                                            </children>
                                        </HBox>
                                        <CustomTextField fx:id="txtWorkingEstimatedTime" alignment="CENTER"
                                                         doubleFormatterEnabled="true" maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0"
                                                         VBox.vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                                    </children>
                                </VBox>
                                <VBox alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                                    <children>
                                        <HBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                            <children>
                                                <Label text="Customer Price" textFill="WHITE">
                                                    <font>
                                                        <Font size="17.0"/>
                                                    </font>
                                                </Label>
                                            </children>
                                        </HBox>
                                        <CustomTextField fx:id="txtWorkingCustomerPrice" alignment="CENTER"
                                                         doubleFormatterEnabled="true" maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0"
                                                         prefHeight="25.0"/>
                                    </children>
                                </VBox>
                                <VBox alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                                    <children>
                                        <HBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                            <children>
                                                <Label text="Machine Price" textFill="WHITE">
                                                    <font>
                                                        <Font size="17.0"/>
                                                    </font>
                                                </Label>
                                            </children>
                                        </HBox>
                                        <CustomTextField fx:id="txtWorkingMachinePrice" alignment="CENTER"
                                                         doubleFormatterEnabled="true" maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="40.0"/>
                                    </children>
                                </VBox>
                            </children>
                        </HBox>
                    </children>
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets/>
                    </HBox.margin>
                    <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </HBox>
                <HBox spacing="5.0"
                      style="-fx-border-color: rgb(255,255,255, 0.5); -fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-radius: 0 0 6 6;"
                      HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                    <children>
                        <VBox alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                            <children>
                                <HBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                    <children>
                                        <Label text="Show Count Down?" textFill="WHITE">
                                            <font>
                                                <Font size="17.0"/>
                                            </font>
                                        </Label>
                                    </children>
                                </HBox>
                                <HBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                    <children>
                                        <CheckBox fx:id="cbShowCountDown" mnemonicParsing="false"/>
                                    </children>
                                </HBox>
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                    </children>
                </HBox>
                <VBox alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <children>
                        <HBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                            <children>
                                <Button id="save_button" fx:id="btnUpdatePrices" mnemonicParsing="false"
                                        onAction="#updatePricesBtnPressed" text="Update" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"
                                        VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                    <graphic>
                                        <ImageView cache="true" fitHeight="18.0" fitWidth="79.0" preserveRatio="true"
                                                   smooth="true">
                                            <image>
                                                <Image url="@../images/update_prices.png"/>
                                            </image>
                                        </ImageView>
                                    </graphic>
                                </Button>
                            </children>
                        </HBox>
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

[image: This is the bug:]

thanks for the answers!
Asaf & Dan

Comment: Could you make at a minimal example? I'm pretty sure 75% of the fxml could be removed without changing the behaviour of the relevant part.

Comment: Just a random guess: have you tried turning off `cache="true"` for the `ImageView`. It shouldn't make any difference, but... Otherwise, you probably need to reduce this to a [MCVE] as fabian suggests.

Comment: @NwDx Not sure at all what you mean by that. Imho the view-controller pair should basically be autonomous, but if you did need references to the controllers beyond the scope of where you initialize each one's data, it would be trivial to modify the given code to do that. It makes no difference to the question...

Comment: I had no problems to run your code (even with five instances) and min and max the window, the buttons still show the correct icon. So the problem is your image or on an other part of your app, like your css.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, we completely disabled the CSS and the problem goes on, also tried to change the cache to 'cache="false"' and it didn't help,Could it be a system bug?

Comment: @DanAngel I don't think so, what I have done is: copy your code, removed the `CustomTextField` entries in your fxml, since I don't have it. And then added a 22px image to the button. The image is saved in the root of the project (no ressource folder). I haven't attached any css either. So, there was no problem with maximizing the window and hovering the image button. What platform (OS, JDK version etc.) you are on?